# Picture box not displaying Emgu.cv.mat.toBitmap image

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, windows-forms-designer

Was following a tutorial on YouTube and tried to get my program to display the live video feed from my webcam into the forms picture box but for some reason the webcam comes on but the picture box isn't displaying anything
I have tried checking if the Mat class was returning null.

but it isn't this is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.UI;

namespace FaceRecognitionAttandanceSystem
{
    public partial class StudentAdd : Form
    {
        public string fileName { get; set; }
        VideoCapture capture;
        
        public StudentAdd()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        
        //Open Folder
        private void metroButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "JPEG|*.jpg", ValidateNames = true, Multiselect = false };
            {
                if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    //open file explorer
                    fileName = openFileDialog.FileName;
                    //pick image from file
                    Image img = Image.FromFile(fileName);
                    //Rotates Image by 90degrees
                    img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                    pictureBox2.Image = img;
                }
            }

        }

        //Capture Image
        private void metroButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //If capture is empty start new video capture
            if(capture == null)
            {
                capture = new Emgu.CV.VideoCapture(0);           
            }
            capture.ImageGrabbed += Capture_ImageGrabbed;
            capture.Start();
        }

        private void Capture_ImageGrabbed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Mat mat = new Mat();
                if(mat == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Here you Go");
                }
                capture.Retrieve(mat);
                pictureBox1.Image = mat.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>().ToBitmap<Bgr, Byte>();
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {

            }
        }

        private void metroButton5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is very likely that the `Capture_ImageGrabbed` event is raised on a background thread. And you can only update the UI on the UI thread. You can place a break point in the event-handler and check the thread-debug window to confirm. To fix this you need to move execution to the UI thread. Try:

```
capture.Retrieve(mat);
var bitmap = mat.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>().ToBitmap<Bgr, Byte>();
pictureBox1.Invoke(() =>  pictureBox1.Image = bitmap );
```

You might need to write `Invoke((Action)(() =>  pictureBox1.Image = bitmap) )`, since I think there is some issues with the overload resolution of lambdas with the invoke-method.

Comment: I tried this but sadly it didn't still work, it's a bit confusing cause the web cam comes on but for some reason the picture box just fails to show anything

Comment: @NwosuTy are you sure you actually get any images? Start by placing a breakpoint in the method, and if this is hit, try saving the image to a file. That should help you determine if it is the image gathering that fails, or the image displaying. In my experience not all web camera libraries work well. The library I had best success with was [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125478/Versatile-WebCam-C-library), but I did not test emgu.

Comment: Sorry bro I'm a bit new to all this, so it seems a bit complex,the lines of codes you sent is that all that is needed to move the execution to a ui thread could you please point me to either a document or a yt video that talks about moving executions to a thread

Comment: You might start with [How to make thread safe calls to controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls?view=netdesktop-6.0). But note that the example is a bit old, newer code should probably use tasks instead of thread/backgroundworker.